# altering a hook_form_alter function

Tags: forms, theming

Is it possible to use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) on a `hook_form_alter()` function already defined in another module?

For example, if I want to alter the output of the following hook from the menu module, can I define a function which allows me to alter the renderable array?

```
function menu_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) { ... }
```

I have looked at the documentation but can't seem to find anything that suggests this is allowed/possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you create your own [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function in a custom module, you can modify the same form.

All of the $form variables that are passed into all of the form alter hooks are the same. You will need to specify the form you want to modify by checking for $form_id. $form_id happens to be the third argument passed in!

For example:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == "YOUR_FORM_ID)
    {
        //modify form here.
    }
}
```

There is also the order of execution for the hooks, that you can modify using [hook_module_implements_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7). Using this hook, you can set your module to be executed last.

For example:

```
function MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook)
{
    if ($hook == 'form_alter')
    {
         $group = $implementations['my_module'];
         unset($implementations['my_module']);
         $implementations['my_module'] = $group;
    }
}
```

That should do exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Assigning a weight to your module can also solve the execution order problem.

Answer (score 7):

Not as such, but you can just implement your own version of that alter hook to make the changes you need to, and make sure your implementation runs later on.

To do that you'll need to implement [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter') {
    // Push your module's implementations of hook_form_alter(), and derivatives, 
    // to last in the list. This will make it run after menu_form_node_type_form_alter()
    // so you can alter whatever you need to.
    $group = $implementations['my_module'];
    unset($implementations['my_module']);
    $implementations['my_module'] = $group;
  }
}

function MYMODULE_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Make changes as usual
}
```